# how to resolve "Field 'exists' failed with error in ADF" error?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, exists

There is a pipeline to read files from FTP and i have used 'Get Metadata' Activity to achieve this.
I have variable of type array that holds all the expected files. I have looped through this variable and using a if condition, I am checking if the file exists. Sometimes, the code runs without any issue but sometimes it throws the below error.

> Field 'exists' failed with error: 'Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=System error.,Source=System,''Type=System.Net.InternalException,Message=System error.,Source=System,'.

[image]

[image]

JSON:

```
{
"name": "test1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "File availability summary",
            "description": "Send File not found alert mail",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "avlFiles_final",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": "<Logic app url>",
                "method": "POST",
                "body": {
                    "value": "@variables('avlfiles_final')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach Expected Files",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Intialize cntr to 1 for SNo",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('expectedFiles')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Metadata of FTP",
                        "description": "get metadata of folder in FTP",
                        "type": "GetMetadata",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataset": {
                                "referenceName": "PartnerHub_FTP2_CopyActivity_prr_filename",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "filename": {
                                        "value": "@item()",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "fieldList": [
                                "exists"
                            ],
                            "storeSettings": {
                                "type": "FtpReadSettings",
                                "recursive": true,
                                "enablePartitionDiscovery": false,
                                "useBinaryTransfer": true,
                                "disableChunking": false
                            },
                            "formatSettings": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Check if file exists",
                        "description": "if exists, append to variable 'avlFiles' as available along with file name, otherwise 'Unavailable'",
                        "type": "IfCondition",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Metadata of FTP",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "expression": {
                                "value": "@activity('Metadata of FTP').output.exists",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "ifFalseActivities": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Append avlFiles with Unavailable files",
                                    "type": "AppendVariable",
                                    "dependsOn": [],
                                    "userProperties": [],
                                    "typeProperties": {
                                        "variableName": "avlFiles",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@json(concat('{','\"S.NO\":',variables('cntr'),',\"File Name\":\"',item(),'\",\"File Availability in FTP\":\"Unavailable\"}'))",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "ifTrueActivities": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Append avlFiles with available files",
                                    "type": "AppendVariable",
                                    "dependsOn": [],
                                    "userProperties": [],
                                    "typeProperties": {
                                        "variableName": "avlFiles",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@json(concat('{','\"S.NO\":',variables('cntr'),',\"File Name\":\"',item(),'\",\"File Availability in FTP\":\"Available\"}'))",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "increment and store in temp",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Check if file exists",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "tmp",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@string(add(int(variables('cntr')),1))",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "store temp to counter",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "increment and store in temp",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "cntr",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@variables('tmp')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "avlFiles_final",
            "description": "",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "ForEach Expected Files",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "avlfiles_final",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@{variables('avlFiles')}",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Initialize cntr to 1 for SNo",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "cntr",
                "value": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "expectedFiles": {
            "type": "Array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "@{concat('FILE1.', '20230713', '.1.csv')}",
                "@{concat('FILE2.', '20230713', '.1.csv')}",
                "@{concat('FILE3.', '20230713', '.1.csv')}",
                "@{concat('FILE4.', '20230713', '.1.csv')}"
            ]
        },
        "avlFiles": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "avlfiles_final": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "cntr": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "tmp": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "lastPublishTime": "2023-07-25T19:45:49Z"
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
```

}

Can someone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Can you please share the JOSN of your pipeline? And also confirm whether the lookup which you are performing only contains file names and not folder paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same JSON in my environment, and it is working fine for me.

[image]

As per your requirement, you want to generate serial number along with other keys. To get the incrementing serial number, make sure you checked the **Sequential** in the Foreach.

[image]

And coming to your error at Get Meta data activity, try the below trouble shooting steps to resolve it.

- Check the connection of linked service and try the same pipeline JSON in another pipeline after publishing.
- Check whether it results the same for the other Get meta data activity properties like `size`, `structure`(Pass only the existing file names for these while checking).

It the error still persists, then it's better to raise a [Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for deeper investigation on this issue.

Comment: thanks, the source, here FTP, was down and hence the weird behavior.